# Numba slows down the loop with independent iterations

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba

I'm trying to parallelize a simple python program using `numba`. It consists of two functions. The first one is the simple power method

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def power_method(A, v):
    u = v.copy()
    for i in range(3 * 10**3):
        u = A @ u
        u /= np.linalg.norm(u)
    return u
```

And the second function iterates with the vector `v` over the grid and runs the `power_method` function for various vectors `v`.

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def iterate_grid(A, scale, sz):
    assert A.shape[0] == A.shape[1] == 3
    n = A.shape[0]

    results = np.empty((sz**3, n))
    tmp = np.linspace(-scale, scale, sz)
    
    for i1 in range(sz):
        v = np.empty(n, dtype=np.float64)
        v1 = tmp[i1]
        for i2, v2 in enumerate(tmp):
            for i3, v3 in enumerate(tmp):
                v[0] = v1
                v[1] = v2
                v[2] = v3

                u = power_method(A, v)

                idx = i1 * sz**2 + i2 * sz + i3
                results[idx] = u.copy()
    
    return results
```

Then I run it with

```
n = 3
A = np.random.randn(n, n)
iterate_grid(A, 5.0, 20)
```

All iterations are independent. Moreover, the calculations ideally fall into the cache, so I would expect that parallelizing the first loop with `prange` will give approximately linear acceleration.

However, the wall time for the sequential code is 6.07 s, while for the parallel code

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def iterate_grid(A, scale, sz):
    assert A.shape[0] == A.shape[1] == 3
    n = A.shape[0]

    results = np.empty((sz**3, n))
    tmp = np.linspace(-scale, scale, sz)
    
    for i1 in numba.prange(sz):
        v = np.empty(n, dtype=np.float64)
        v1 = tmp[i1]
        for i2, v2 in enumerate(tmp):
            for i3, v3 in enumerate(tmp):
                v[0] = v1
                v[1] = v2
                v[2] = v3

                u = power_method(A, v)

                idx = i1 * sz**2 + i2 * sz + i3
                results[idx] = u.copy()
    
    return results
```

the wall time is 7.79 s. That is, parallelization slows down the code in this case.

Moreover, as I can see from `iterate_grid.parallel_diagnostics(level=4)`, numba fuses
`tmp = np.linspace(-scale, scale, sz)` and `for i1 in range(sz):` which is incorrect, because I need all values of `tmp` in the inner loops.

Parallelizing the power method is not the task I'm actually trying to solve, it's just a small example on which numba does not behave as I expect. Can you explain to me this behavior of numba and advise me how I can parallelize iterations on the grid to get linear acceleration?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What is `= .copy()` in the penultimate line? Please include a [mre] of how the function is called, the `numba` decorators used and data size, code for the benchmark.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, I'm sorry, it's my inexperience in formatting on stackoverflow:) Now it is fully reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Correctness prevails over performance**. Thus, you need to check results are actually correct before trying the measure the performance of the implementation. And it turns out the result between the sequential and parallel implementations are different (you can use `np.allclose` to check that or plot the array differences). Since the parallel code is basically the same except the use of `prange`, a race condition is very likely to be the cause. Running multiple times the program and checking if results are different is a good way to check for the probable presence of race condition (note the absence of difference does not mean there are no race conditions and other problems can cause non-deterministic results). A practical test on my machine gives very different results.

The thing is **your code looks completely correct**! Generally this means that the problem is due to undefined behaviours or compiler/runtime bugs. A deeper analysis show that the problem does not appear if `tmp = np.linspace(-scale, scale, sz)` is moved within the parallel loop. This is certainly due to a **bug in Numba**.

Assuming the results would be correct, the performance is strongly dependant of the `power_method` function which is not efficient. Indeed, neither Numba nor Numpy are optimized for very small arrays. **Numba does not often optimize out array allocations** except in some specific cases (like explicit allocations in a prange-based loop with detected invariants or [similar cases](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/parallel.html?highlight=Allocation%20hoisting#diagnostics) as pointed out by @max9111): arrays are allocated on the heap using a quite **slow allocation** method. On top of that **allocations do not scale** preventing any parallel speed up. An optimization is to do the operation manually using 3 variables. Here is an optimized implementation:

```py
@numba.njit
def fast_power_method(A, v1, v2, v3):
    # Unpacking
    # Note: there is no need for a copy here
    u1, u2, u3 = v1, v2, v3
    A11, A12, A13 = A[0]
    A21, A22, A23 = A[1]
    A31, A32, A33 = A[2]

    for i in range(3_000):
        # Optimized matrix multiplication
        t1 = u1 * A11 + u2 * A12 + u3 * A13
        t2 = u1 * A21 + u2 * A22 + u3 * A23
        t3 = u1 * A31 + u2 * A32 + u3 * A33

        # Renormalization
        # Note: multiplications are faster than divisions
        norm = np.sqrt(t1**2 + t2**2 + t3**2)
        inv_norm = 1.0 / norm
        u1 = t1 * inv_norm
        u2 = t2 * inv_norm
        u3 = t3 * inv_norm

    return u1, u2, u3

@numba.njit
def iterate_grid(A, scale, sz):
    assert A.shape[0] == A.shape[1] == 3
    n = A.shape[0]

    results = np.empty((sz**3, n))
    tmp = np.linspace(-scale, scale, sz)

    for i1 in range(sz):
        v = np.empty(n, dtype=np.float64)
        v1 = tmp[i1]
        for i2, v2 in enumerate(tmp):
            for i3, v3 in enumerate(tmp):
                u1, u2, u3 = fast_power_method(A, v1, v2, v3)

                idx = i1 * sz**2 + i2 * sz + i3
                results[idx, 0] = u1
                results[idx, 1] = u2
                results[idx, 2] = u3
    
    return results
```

This implementation takes 0.4 seconds while the initial version takes about 10 seconds. Thus, it is **25 times faster** while still being sequential. Results are slightly different due to floating-point rounding and non-associativity. Note that using `prange` with this version is 5 times faster on my 6-core machine so it scale well but results are still wrong for the same reason. This shows at least that allocations was certainly the bottleneck.

The rule of thumb is to *check results* and that *micro-optimizations* can result in a faster execution than using multiple cores (especially for heavily numerical codes).

**UPDATE:** I filled a Numba bug available [here](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/8184).

Comment: Numba tries to optimize away array allocations if you enable `parallel=True`. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html (Allocation hoisting)

Comment: @max9111 Indeed. In parallel codes and in specific cases. It looks like a brittle optimization since it is often not applied on realistic codes with many temporary arrays (eg. the one of the OP as well as many codes I wrote so far). Sad stack-based allocations are not yet possible (or even malloc/new tracking&elimination Clang is able to successfully do).

Comment: An implementation for stack-arrays in Numba. eg. https://github.com/max9111/numba/blob/main/numba/np/unsafe/stack.py

Comment: @max9111 Interesting, but this is not mainlined yet isn't it? If so, this is a pretty big piece of code that only worse using it for sufficiently large codes. This also require the user to be skilled since stack allocations causes issues in loops (which can be hard to detect since most profiling/debugging tools fail to interact with Numba codes and inlined function should use the stack of the parent function and may be called in an loop too -- possibly recursively). Still, its better than the current frustrating state of Numba ;) .